# 20.04 too long to boot up and too long to open apps, other OS worked fine

Tags: boot

It is taking around two minutes for Ubuntu 20.04 to access the log in screen than a further minute to boot up.

Also some applications, e.g. Kdenlive, taking 90 seconds+ to load.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which *other* OS? [edit] and add the additional info.

Comment: can you edit the result of systemd-analyze blame into your question? you can look in logs to look for any errors too.

Comment: I have used ubuntu 14.04,18.04 and linux mint.Now, I am using ubuntu 20.04.1.I also have found that ubuntu 20.04.1 is way bit slower in boot than 18.04 or 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your replies. The other OS is Linux Lite, No, I'm afraid I can't edit the systemd-analyze. However, I did add the following into the .profile in the Home setting, QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=gtk2. After restarting Ubuntu, I opened Kdenlive and it took 35 seconds for it to open. Then I closed Kdenlive and re-opened it again, this time it took 4.3 seconds for Kdenlive to open. However, when I shut down and re-launched Ubuntu, at first attempt Kdenlive took 35 seconds to open, then I closed it, and it re-opened in 4 seconds.  So I opened the app quicker, but there may be another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your computer doesn't have enough ram to run full Ubuntu? It needs about 2 GB of RAM to run correctly. If you don't have enough, it takes a very long time to load and lags a lot.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying to me. It isn't a hardware issue, I have 8GB of RAM. I have installed another Linux distro and it works fine. Thanks. Pete